# How to mock nested third party dependencies?

Tags: go, testing, interface, mocking

Example third party API usage:

```
fund doSomething(api *api.Client) {
    ...
    result, err := api.Logical().Write(val1, val2)
    ...
}
```

I can handle the initial call to `Logical()` with my own interface:

```
type API interface {
    Logical() *api.Logical
}

...

doSomething(&MockAPI{}) // Assuming MockAPI implements API
```

However, this now brings the problem into sight: the `Logical()` method has to have the above function signature, otherwise, I couldn't substitute the real `api` object in for my interface. Since the `*api.Logical` type is nested within the third party API library, I cannot simply mock it out with another interface:

```
type Writer interface {
    Write(string, string) Result, error
}

type API interface {
    Logical() *Writer
}

...

doSomething(&api.Client{}) // Doesn't implement Logical() *Writer
```

How would I mock this API call out so I can return custom data and not hit a live service? If it helps, this is based on an [actual API](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/api/client.go).

Comment: Are you asking how to mock it, or how to access the mock from your code? For the former: Just write a mock. There's no magic formula. For the latter: dependency injection.

Comment: @JoshuaGilman https://play.golang.com/p/joTfxqamDiN

Comment: Related: [Mocking Hashicorp vault in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771228/mocking-hashicorp-vault-in-go/57773764#57773764)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer here is to just avoid the chained function call altogether.

```
type Writer interface {
    Write(string, string) Result, error
}

func doSomething(writer Writer) {
    ...
    result, err := writer.Write(val1, val2)
    ...
}

...

doSomething(api.Client.Logical())
```

Now I can implement my own `Writer` and use it for mocking.